# How do I remove the end of an NSMutableString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have the following `NSMutableString`:

```
@"1*2*3*4*5"
```

I want to find the first * and remove everything after it, so my `string = @"1";` How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"1*2*3*4*5"];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"*"];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    [string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(range.location, [string length] - range.location)];
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a crash when the string contains no *. How do I handle that?

Comment: @EthanAllen check if the method returns nil.

Comment: actually if the string contains no *, rangeOfString will return NSNotFound, not nil. You can test `if(range != NSNotFound)` then do what you want to do

Comment: @Rickay means `if (range.location != NSNotFound)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to divide this string by a separator and get the first object

```
NSString *result = [[MyString componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

After calling  `componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"` you'll get the array of strings, separated by *,and the first object is right what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another strategy, using the very flexible `NSScanner`.

```
NSString* beginning;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"1*2*3*4*5"];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"*" intoString:&beginning];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-rangeOfString:` to find the index of the first asterisk and use that with `-substringToIndex:` to extract a substring from the original input. Something like this perhaps...

```
NSMutableString *input = @"1*2*3*4*5";

// Finds the range of the first instance. See NSString docs for more options.
NSRange firstAsteriskRange = [input rangeOfString:@"*"];
NSString *trimmedString = [input substringToIndex:firstAsteriskRange.location + 1];
```

Comment: This would return the asterisk itself.